# Java (JVM) on ARMv7 (more specifically Cubox or BeagleBoard)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jvm, arm, hsqldb

I was wondering if anyone have gotten Java up and running on a BeagleBoard or Cubox? I'm thinking about buying one for a project I'm working on on my spare time, but as parts of this project is written in Java I first wanted to know if these tiny computers can run a JVM at all?

From what I read on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html there are editions for ARM, and Solid-Run (the manufacturer behind Cubox) have also written some info on their wiki: http://www.solid-run.com/mw/index.php/Oracle_Java_on_CuBox.

However, what I would need to know is:

1. Can I consider ARM JVM == x86/x64 JVM in terms of functionality (a.k.a. "will my code run without changes") (my code is pretty non-graphical, mainly a HTTP API)?
2. Are there any license "problems" with JVM on ARM (compared to JVM on x86/x64)? That is, if I suddenly want to mass-produce my little spare-time hobby project and sell Cuboxes, will Oracle sue me?
3. Anyone have any experience with Hibernate/HSQLDB on ARM?

Perhaps too many questions in one, but I think they're all related enough to be put in the same thread. In general, I want to know more about JVM on ARM and how developed and mature it is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to 1 and 2 are on the Oracle page. "development is free, but royalties are required upon deployment on anything other than general purpose systems.  In all cases, these products are fully Java SE compliant"

As for 3, I don't know about Hibernate (which shouldn't be a problem), but HSQLDB has been used on ARM by Symbian and others at least since 5 years ago.

Comment: After your answer I decided to give and try and pre-ordered a Cubox, If I remember I'll post back here with the results when I have tested :)

Comment: Java runs fine on the Cubox, identical functionality to x86/x64 JVMs. I just installed Ubuntu Core and apt-get:ed the openjdk, plain and simple.

Comment: How about performance? Can you run tomcat with some web framework and hibernate?